# How could I store each character being selected into a varaible? JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

**Full Html Code:**

```
<script src="/Resources/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Resources/JQueryPlugins/Ease.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function codeAddress() {
        // Gathers String Content
        var el = document.querySelectorAll(".con-1");

        // Stores text, and prepares it for use
        var myString = el[0].textContent;   

        // Sets a blank array ready to store myString characters at certain positions
        var matchedIndexes = [];

        // Main function, Gathers characters W,T,M,P in myString
        // As long as (I) has a lower value than myStrings length it keeps searching for characters
        for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
            // Gathers characters W T M P
            if (myString[i] == "W" || myString[i] == "T" || myString[i] == "M" || myString[i] == "P") {
                matchedIndexes.push(new myMatch(myString[i], i));
            }
        }

        console.log(matchedIndexes);

        function myMatch(position, character) {
            // Writes to console the position of the character
            this.position = position;

            // Writes to console the character that was collected
            this.character = character;
        }
    }

    // When the window is loaded call codeAddress function
    window.onload = codeAddress;
</script>
<div class="pro-1">
    <div class="con-1 noselect">Welcome To My Playground</div>
    <div class="sod-1 noselect">Stuff Happens Here.</div>
</div>
```

**Pointing Towards Specific Problem**

```
// Main function, Gathers characters W,T,M,P in myString
// As long as (I) has a lower value than myStrings length it keeps searching for characters
for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    // Gathers characters W T M P
    if (myString[i] == "W" || myString[i] == "T" || myString[i] == "M" || myString[i] == "P") {
        matchedIndexes.push(new myMatch(myString[i], i));
    }
}
```

I would like the characters **W T M P** to be stored into a variable.

Preferably one variable but I could work around with multiple.

I don't know how to set them as a variable.

Comment: What's wrong with this? Are they not being collected in `matchedIndexes`?

Comment: i fear the question is not very clear, in what way your code doesn't do what you expect? (if we except that you inversed the order of `position` and `character` when you create your objects)

Comment: To be honest, This code was from an example. I am new to JS. Although I believe I understand most of it because I commented all of it without reading what everything does from the example author. I dont fully understand arrays. What I am trying to do is make the characters W T M P's style display none. using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Based on your comments***;

You are already collecting these letters in to a variable (array) - `matchedIndexes`.

Unfortunately, what you want to do (hide each character using display: none) can't be achieved in the way you're hoping. Each of these are characters within a string - not an element. One way to achieve this is to remove the characters from the string and put it back in to your div, like so;

```
if (myString[i] != "W" || myString[i] != "T" || myString[i] != "M" || myString[i] != "P") {
    matchedIndexes.push(new myMatch(myString[i], i));
}

var text = matchedIndexes.toString();
document.getElementsByClassName(".sod-1")[0].innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: I get a error saying: "Uncaught typeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined". this is referencing the last line in ur example

Answer (score 0):

Extend the variable:

```
$somestring='';
for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    $somestring+=myString[i];
}
console.log($somestring);
```